# How to avoid the rigid body "push apart" while another rigidbody is inside?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, smoke-simulation, collision, rigidbody

Here goes with the scene, The simulation did "explode" while another rigid body is inside, the gap I gave was big enough and the collision margin tried 0.000001/0.00001/0.0001/0.04/1 and convex hull or mesh, that's going wrong too :(

**Video Link** :
https://vimeo.com/729547384

[image: Gap Between Fracture Rigidbody and Inner rigidbody]

**Question** :

1. How to avoid "Push apart" happening while a rigid body is inside so the fracture cells could collide with the rigid inside and fall naturally?

**Remarks** :

1. I would like to have the simulation from the "expected sim" with the rigid body inside collide correctly.
2. The "Expected Simulation" is without an inner rigid body enabled.
3. I am welcome for any concept or tutorial that will open my mind!

**Blend File if required**
https://we.tl/t-QYj2c4E53c

Comment: make sure the Collision shape is *Mesh* and Sensitivity *Collision Margin* is zero for **all objects**

Comment: Still results the same :(

Comment: yes i did , but the rigid inner still makes the fracture "explode"

Here was the setting
https://imgur.com/a/amWVVzS

Comment: something weird. your weights also seem unrealistic, i see a weight of 10,000 kg too much. and it acts weird when i change the weight to 1kg

Comment: yeah, struggling to solve the problem . Thank a lot !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand what "convex hull" means:

The resulting shape is something, if you would wrap your mesh with a tape.

I added here a geometry nodes setup to one piece so you see what convex hull makes out of your mesh.

[image]

So of course every single piece of your outer cylinder would intersect with your inner cylinder, because you set it to convex hull.

And every intersection of two rigid bodies in a simple world like Blender physics isn't possible (and also not in real world if you exclude deforming). That's why it explodes.

So set them all to mesh, scale them down a bit, play a bit with settings (e.g. use "normal" weights, not that huge as you took, turn down margin to 0, lower bounciness...) and then finally you might get:

[image]

repaired file to check out:

[image]

Comment: Thank for the details explanation. appreciate the answer , you help a lot!

Comment: If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. Thank you.

Comment: i did exactly that, but it still explodes. i even reduced the size with visible gaps https://blend-exchange.com/b/7BdGb7L7

Comment: Did you delete the bake?

Comment: yes it is deleted. were you able to see it in the file? i've been tinkering around for 2 hours. it makes no sense xd and by the way if i make the gaps as huge as yours then it works too but it should work with a minimal gap not visible to the eyes

Comment: make them just a little bit smaller, change substeps and solver to 10 then it worked for me [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCwO7.gif i scaled them to 0.964

Comment: the problem is - if you make the gap too small, blender physics won't make it (with mesh). unfortunately the cell fracture works only for convex hull with invisible gaps (so the shape mustn't have hole or be concave)...at least i didn't make that work. Or you use other tricks like shape keys or "blending" an invisible object in.

Comment: and blender physics is pretty "limited" - just e.g. i never made a physics simulation better or working by increasing substeps...in contrary to cloth where increasing quality is working most of the time. The more complicated the meshes are...the less Blender physics would work. So you should try to keep objects "simple" ;)

Comment: yeah i think you're right. thanks for your explanation! :)

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: I found that "split Impluse " and triangulate mesh does help Mesh collision increase simulation accuracy.